# What are the effect of reroll 1s and 6s once on 1d6 die?

Tags: statistics, dice

I've read that rerolling 1s pushes your average from 3.5 to about ~3.9. Does rerolling 6s along with 1s once renomalize the average?

If you add dice does this change the bell curve?

What does the curve look like if you must continue to reroll 1s and 6s until you have none?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9201), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Sometimes you say "reroll once" sometimes you just say "reroll." You cn hardly get 3.9 if you rreroll all 1s until you get a non-one, because then the obvious expected value is $4.$ So presumably, you meant "once" there, too?